# My application running at lollipop version but can't run at higher versions

Tags: android

My application running at lollipop version but can't run at higher versions. This error occurs:

[image]

Comment: Welcome on board . Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first .

Comment: Please post code and error log

Comment: from sdk version 23 you have to ask users for permissions https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in 6.0 or above versions , you need to use runtime permissions.
Follow the sample code below :

```
public void checkPer()
{

    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SubCategoryActivity.this,"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    } else {
        // user already provided permission
        // perform function for what you want to achieve
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    boolean canUseExternalStorage = false;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                canUseExternalStorage = true;
            }

            if (!canUseExternalStorage) {
                Toast.makeText(SubCategoryActivity.this, "You cannot see images without requested permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // user now provided permission
                // perform function for what you want to achieve

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will help you my friend.